# How to use cookies in a Rack middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, rack

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to use the `cookies.signed` method in a Rack middleware. I need that because I would like to authenticate a user directly in the middleware than of using a `before_filter` in the `application_controller.rb` file.

For example, if I use that method in a controller this way:

```
cookies.signed[:user_id']
```

I get

```
--- 
- 1 # This is the id of the current signed in user
- a64ee3asdtjhcc7b35fcb280956be00ba27f94d48dfe4291c06db7d57577d5893 # This is the cookie salt
```

but if I use that in a Rack middleware (of the same application) this way:

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
request.cookies.signed[:user_id']
```

I get

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `signed' for #<Hash:0x00000103333d40>
```

So, **how can I make it possible to use that method in a middleware? How can I get the user id so that I can authenticate that?**

---

Maybe I have to include\extend, for example, the ActionDispatch... if so, how?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do this:

```
  request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
  request.cookie_jar.signed[:user_id] #=> 1
```

You can check out [.../action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L4-8) on github to read more about exactly what is going on.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction but still raised the same error (using Rails 4.2.7). The issue was the missing application secrets in the `env`. Replacing the first line with the following worked: `ActionDispatch::Request.new(Rails.application.env_config.merge(env))`.

Comment: ActionDispatch is a good answer for rails. However the question asks for a Rack middleware solution.

Answer (score 6):

A already initialized cookie jar is present in the `env` hash.

```
env['action_dispatch.cookies'].signed[:user_id]
```

The example above is equivalent to call the below in a `ActionController::Base` instance context:

```
cookies.signed[:user_id]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `env['action_dispatch.cookies']` isn't available for any rack apps. It's only set very late in the request processing.